# How to execute ui change right after jquery.effect event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a bounce effect in my jquery ui. During the bounce there is a color change, is there any way I can set the color back to normal right after the bounce finish?

```
  $(div).effect("bounce", { times:2 }, 200);
```

Is there any event handler in jQuery related to animate or effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation on effect shows that it is called as follows:

```
effect( effect, [options], [speed], [callback] )
```

So, you can simply pass a function to the `callback` parameter and that will run once the effect completes.

Comment: missed that piece, i will give it a shot. Thanks.